# How to handle www folder permissions with SFTP

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, sftp

I have a VPS and I have to upload files my web application by SFTP connections.

I ofter have probems with permissions, when I upload files I have always to force a `chown` to move all my uploads to www-data user and group, to let apache handle it.

Is this the common way to do so? I don't think to set www-data as primary group is a good idea (my user do many other things a part of uploading file in www folder!).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add the user account you’re uploading with to the `www-data` group:

```
sudo adduser ubuntu www-data
```

This will allow you to overwrite files owned by the Apache user without giving the web server elevated permissions.